# Trying to find a movie about a crazy kid hunting down killer mobsters

Tags: identify-this-movie

I just saw a couple of snippets of this movie a couple of years ago but it seemed interesting. A little like 'Home Alone' but with a mean streak. This expressionless faced teen was actually trying to kill the mob bad guys. There's a place for it in my video library I think; somewhere between 'Home Alone' and 'The Exorcist'.

From what I remember, the kid never says anything and is/was some kind of psychiatric patient. His parents are killed by the bad guys in a home invasion type robbery looking for money.  It's filmed in a rural wooded setting with a farm type house with some outbuildings and the kid sets different wicked traps for the bad guys as they chase him around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it [The Aggression Scale](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1816597/)? The Storyline seems pretty similar.

> This movie is about a newly bailed mob boss named Bellavance (Ray Wise) and his band of hit men (including Derek Mears- 'Jason Voorhees') who head off to find $500,000 that has gone missing. They take out anybody that has come in contact with the money, but they eventually track down a family that they believe have the money. They don't realize that the son (Owen) has been involved in some unsavory incidents as a result of his "Aggression". They are soon to find out just who and what they're up against.

The trailer: